# Pass Data from PHP to Javascript and Vice Versa

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a php file that echos JSON encoded arrays, the contents of which are pulled from a remote database.

I want to be able to pass this data from the PHP file to a Javascript file linked to a running HTML file displayed in the browser.

What are the best practises for passing data, particularly in JSON format fromPHP to Javascript...

Comment: Look up this popular thing called "Ajax".

Comment: Can you clarify? Is the PHP script with the arrays generating the HTML file, which has the reference to the JS script? Or is the JS script querying a separate PHP script?

Comment: the latter. the html file will trigger a js function that queries the php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The jQuery Javascript library](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) provides a bunch of great ways for handling Ajax.  JSON is a wonderful format for client/server communication, even as-is.  XML is also good.

If you are talking about long polling, you may also want to look into [COMET](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start)